# EF Core : join two entities without key

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities:

```
[Keyless]
public class F1
{
    public int Shop { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public List<F2> ListF2 { get; set; } = new List<Fac1>();
}

[Keyless]
public class F2
{
    public int Shop { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int row { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Insert F1 (1, 1)
Insert F1 (1, 2)
Insert F1 (2, 1)

Insert F2 (1, 1, 1, banana)
Insert F2 (1, 1, 2, grape)
Insert F2 (2, 1, 1, apple)
```

I want to have this for convert to json with two elements

```
1, 1, ([ 1, banana ] [ 2, grape ])
2, 1, ([ 1, apple ])

List<F1> F1s = _context.F1.Where(p => p.Shop <= 2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no requirement in SQL or LINQ for a "key" when joining tables or collections (in SQL indexes may provide large performance boosts but are in no way required).

Secondly: you don't need a join here because you have the association `F1.ListF2` which LINQ can follow.

```cs
var res = await (from a in context.F1
                 where a.Shop <= 2
                 select new {
                    a.Shop,
                    a.Numbers,
                    F2 = (from b in a.F2.List
                          select new {
                            b.Row,
                            n.Name
                          })
                 }
                ).ToListAsync();
```

This can be fed into a JSON serialiser (like `System.Text.Json`):

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(res);
```

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'b => new { 
    row = b.row, 
    Name = b.Name
 }' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: What happens if you add a `ToList()` to the inner query? (I don't have a convenient place to test this.)